Error of 'Execution context was destroyed' when using Puppeteer
I'm trying to build an automated tool where a URL from NYTimes is passed to Archive.vn so I can see the full article. I am trying to build the tool in JavaScript, so I'm using the Puppeteer and Cheerio libraries. However, I keep getting the following exception:
Exception has occurred: ProtocolError: Protocol error (Runtime.callFunctionOn): Execution context was destroyed.

The code successfully passes the URL to Archive.vn and loads the resulting NYTimes page. But I suspect the issue is on line 36 of my code, but cannot figure out what exactly the issue is.
import axios from 'axios';
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import cheerio from 'cheerio';

async function getTopStories() {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(
            'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/news/v3/content/all/all.json', {
                params: {
                    'api-key': 'XXXXXXXX', 
                },
            }
        );

        // Extract the first article URL (you can modify this as needed)
        const articleUrl = response.data.results[0].url;
        console.log('Fetched NYT article URL:', articleUrl);
        return articleUrl;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching NYT top stories:', error);
        return null;
    }
}

async function archiveArticle(articleUrl) {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
        const page = await browser.newPage({ timeout: 30000 });

        // Navigate to the archive.vn website
        await page.goto(`https://www.archive.vn/?run=1&url=${encodeURIComponent(articleUrl)}`, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2',timeout: 30000000 });
        console.log('Navigated to archive.vn');


        // Wait for the article to load (you may need to adjust the wait time)
        await page.waitForSelector('.site-content', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2',timeout: 300000 });
        console.log('Article content loaded');

        // Get the HTML content of the loaded article
        const articleHtml = await page.$eval('section[name="articleBody"]', (section) => {
            return section.innerHTML; // Use innerHTML to get the content within the section
        });
        console.log('Article HTML:', articleHtml);
        

        // Parse the HTML using Cheerio
        const $ = cheerio.load(articleHtml);

        // Extract the article title, author, date, and full article content
        const articleTitle = $('h1').text();
        const articleAuthor = $('.author').text();
        const articleDate = $('.date').text();
        const articleContent = $('.article-content').text();

        // Print the extracted information (you can save it to a database instead)
        console.log(`Title: ${articleTitle}`);
        console.log(`Author: ${articleAuthor}`);
        console.log(`Date: ${articleDate}`);
        console.log(`Content: ${articleContent}`);

        await browser.close();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error archiving article:', error.message);
    }
}

// Example usage
(async () => {
    const nyTimesArticleUrl = await getTopStories();
    if (nyTimesArticleUrl) {
        await archiveArticle(nyTimesArticleUrl);
    } else {
        console.error('Failed to retrieve NYT article URL.');
    }
})();

I tried to change the Element within the waitForSelector method, such as .app, but still get the same error.
Code where the ArticleUrl is fixed:
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import cheerio from 'cheerio';


async function archiveArticle(articleUrl) {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
        const page = await browser.newPage({ timeout: 30000 });
        const articleUrl = 'https://www.nytimes.com/2024/04/02/world/middleeast/biden-gaza-aid-attack.html'

        // Navigate to the archive.vn website
        await page.goto(`https://www.archive.vn/?run=1&url=${encodeURIComponent(articleUrl)}`, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2',timeout: 30000000 });
        console.log('Navigated to archive.vn');


        // Wait for the article to load (you may need to adjust the wait time)
        await page.waitForSelector('.site-content', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2',timeout: 300000 });
        console.log('Article content loaded');

        // Get the HTML content of the loaded article
        const articleHtml = await page.$eval('section[name="articleBody"]', (section) => {
            return section.innerHTML; // Use innerHTML to get the content within the section
        });
        console.log('Article HTML:', articleHtml);

        // Parse the HTML using Cheerio
        const $ = cheerio.load(articleHtml);

        // Extract the article title, author, date, and full article content
        const articleTitle = $('h1').text();
        const articleAuthor = $('.author').text();
        const articleDate = $('.date').text();
        const articleContent = $('.article-content').text();

        // Print the extracted information (you can save it to a database instead)
        console.log(`Title: ${articleTitle}`);
        console.log(`Author: ${articleAuthor}`);
        console.log(`Date: ${articleDate}`);
        console.log(`Content: ${articleContent}`);

        await browser.close();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error archiving article:', error.message);
    }
}

archiveArticle();


Your code looks basically OK to me, other than some antipatterns like swallowing errors and using networkidle and Cheerio. Without the API keys, I can't reproduce the behavior. Assuming the response from the first request is OK, can you hardcode an articleUrl in so the issue is reproducible? Thanks.

This error typically happens when you try to use stale element handles: grab some handle, navigate or do something on the page that causes the handle to be removed, then try to use the stale handle. It could maybe also happen if you forget to await a promise. But you're not doing any of that so I can't see any logical issue here.

Edited my post to include a fixed URL for the ArticleUrl. Many thanks.

Running your code doesn't reproduce the error on my end. That error usually occurs when DOM manipulation or page navigations cause your element handles to go stale.
I don't see the selectors you're using in the final page (there's a redirect to get there, which is possibly why you're using networkidle, which is normally discouraged*). I'd pull the data out of the metadata JSON available in a script in the static response, then cancel any unnecessary requests to optimize performance. Add a user agent so you don't need to run headfully.
Here's my solution:
import puppeteer from "puppeteer"; // ^22.6.0

const archiveArticle = async articleUrl => {
  let browser;
  try {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    const ua =
      "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36";
    await page.setUserAgent(ua);
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);
    page.on("request", req => {
      req.resourceType() === "document"
        ? req.continue()
        : req.abort();
    });
    const url = `https://www.archive.vn/?run=1&url=${encodeURIComponent(articleUrl)}`;
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "domcontentloaded"});
    const extractMetadata = `
      [...document.querySelectorAll('[type="application/ld+json"]')]
        .find(e => e.textContent.includes('"author":'))
        ?.textContent
    `;
    await page.waitForFunction(extractMetadata);
    const text = await page.evaluate(extractMetadata);
    const start = text.indexOf("{");
    const end = text.lastIndexOf("}") + 1;
    const metadata = JSON.parse(text.slice(start, end));
    const articleEl = await page.waitForSelector(
      '[name="articleBody"]'
    );
    const content = await articleEl.evaluate(
      el => el.textContent
    );
    return {content, metadata};
  } finally {
    await browser?.close();
  }
};

const articleUrl = "<Your URL>";
archiveArticle(articleUrl)
  .then(article => {
    console.log(article.metadata.headline);
    console.log(article.metadata.datePublished);
    console.log(article.metadata.author.map(e => e.name));
    console.log(article.content.slice(0, 78));
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));

Output:
Biden Outraged After Israel’s Military Claims Aid Convoy Attack Was a Mistake
2024-04-03T00:09:39.000Z
[ 'Ben Shpigel', 'Cassandra Vinograd', 'Erica L. Green' ]
President Biden said he was “outraged and heartbroken” by the killing of seven

Other remarks:

Don't swallow errors and return null, let the caller handle them. I/O and logging should happen at the top level, not as side effects inside logic functions.

Avoid using a separate HTML parser with Puppeteer. Either the data is available statically or it isn't. If it's available statically and you're not being blocked, use fetch and Cheerio. Otherwise, us Puppeteer, but don't serialize the DOM unless you have good reason to--work with it directly.

* Regarding networkidle, the Playwright (Microsoft's rewrite of Puppeteer) docs say:

DISCOURAGED consider operation to be finished when there are no
network connections for at least 500 ms. Don't use this method for
testing, rely on web assertions to assess readiness instead.

Although It says "for testing", you shouldn't use it for scraping either, since it's slow and waits for way more resource than you need (possibly forever, if enough long-running requests remain open). Almost always use 'domcontentloaded' and a precise predicate, as shown in my code.

waitUntil is not a valid property for page.waitForSelector. Only visible, hidden and timeout are valid at the time of writing.

Consider passing page into the function so you can reuse it and don't have to open and close a browser per-call. The caller should generally manage these resources except in one-off scripts.


Disclosure: I'm the author of linked blog posts.

Thanks for this. I applied your code but always get the "Cannot find execution context with given executionContextId" exception at the line await page.waitForFunction(extractMetadata);

Can you provide system/package details? Which version of Puppeteer are you using? It could be related to how certain versions handle the redirect. You could try waitUntil: "networkidle2" instead of waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" temporarily to see if that handles the redirect properly (it's not a great solution, but might avoid the error for you).

Thanks for your help. I updated to the latest stable release but still get an error. I think I'll use Python and beautifulsoup as it seems to be a bit easier to work with.

Are you running my code exactly as it is here, with the URL swapped in? I just ran it 10 times and it still works for me on Ubuntu 22.04 and Puppeteer 22.6. Is the error you're getting the same as before or different? If you can use BeautifulSoup, great, but it may not work since data is populated after load. BeautifulSoup only works on static HTML strings, usually returned by requests, so it's a different use case than Puppeteer. Fetch + Cheerio is similar to Requests + BS but in Node.

Thank you - I somehow don't get the error anymore. I didn't change a thing so not sure why it's running now. Thank you so much for your help and patience - I'm still a newbie to SO and Javascript.

No problem, thanks for confirming. Even with 10 runs there's a possibility that the redirect isn't handled perfectly and may fail on some machines, so what you're seeing may not be totally out of line. There are adjustments that might resolve it, but I'm still seeing good results here so I'll keep it as is for now.
